# Remote debugging with VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to follow [these steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/debug-c-code-on-linux-from-visual-studio.aspx) on how to debug a linux application with VS.

The problem I'm having is at step 8 and it consists of VS not being able to find the command "Debug.GDBLaunch".

I'm running VS version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL and I have the Visual C++ Cross Platform Mobile Development 1.0 installed.

Are there any other requirements I'm missing and if not, what's the problem?

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: @DenDelimarsky: Command "Debug.GDBLaunch" is not valid

Answer (score 0):

I had success with Debug.MIDebugLaunch command. Please look at https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Start-debugging-other-platforms-using-the-MIEngine

Comment: Tried this but it seems to be looping forever on "Initializing Debugger". Any ideas?

Comment: @user1233963 Try to use the following options file: <LocalLaunchOptions
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/MDDDebuggerOptions/2014"
    MIDebuggerPath="gdb.exe"
    MIDebuggerServerAddress="localhost:1234">
</LocalLaunchOptions>. It worked for me instead of TcpLaunchOptions.